# 64-bit ColdFusion 8 Download

Tags: coldfusion, download, coldfusion-8

I’m migrating one of our ColdFusion 8 servers to a 64-bit server and was wondering if anyone knows of a place to download the 64-bit version of ColdFusion 8?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download CF8 64 bit from here:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=coldfusion8

Comment: ColdFusion 8 is no longer available to download and no longer appears on this page.

Answer (score 2):

Just be sure to notice that in CF8, there was only support for 64-bit in CF 8 Enterprise (or Developer) but not CF 8 Standard. That was changed in CF9, so that you can run 64-bit on either edition.

(Here's something perhaps related, if yours is a move to a more modern 64-bit version of Windows: beware as well that if you're deploying on a server running IIS 7, that was also not supported in CF 9 (or 8) and required manual tweaks to get it to work. CF 9.0.1 (the free updater that you install on top of 9.0) does add that support.)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think they introduced 64-bit with ColdFusion 8.0.1.

I learned this after I had submitted the above question. Thanks, Paul

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/64_bit.html

Comment: Paul, I just want to be clear about what you're asking. My point of clarification was simply that it wasn't until CF 9 that 64-bit was supported in CF Standard. You're not contending against that, right?
 
Instead, I sense you may just be clarifying that it wasn't 8.0 that added that 64-bit support but specifically 8.0.1. If so, fair enough. The link Matt offered would indeed have given one that release, since Adobe updated the installer for 8 to include 8.0.1. I just didn't want readers to think they'd get 64 bit if they had only a CF 8 Standard license. They will not. :-)

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for clarifying Charlie. :)